# Twisted - Matching current connection in factory.clients with unique ID

Tags: python, database, twisted

I'm trying to implement a chat server using Twisted but am having difficulty pairing unique user IDs (stored in a DB) with current sessions stored in factory.clients. In the following code, I assume a newly connected user will send its user ID immediately after joining the server. With this assumption, I take the last entry in factory.clients to be the index of its connection and store it in a DB. There are many flaws to this approach and I'm trying to determine a better one.

My main question: what is the best way to pair a unique user id with a connection?

```
class ChatPlace(Protocol):
def connectionMade(self):
    self.factory.clients.append(self)
    print "clients are ", self.factory.clients
    print "connection from", self.transport.getPeer().host

def connectionLost(self, reason):
    self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):

        #Variables and data parsing logic removed for brevity

        #The cur_connect_idx should be mapped to factory.clients but I'm not sure of the best way
        cur_connect_idx = len(self.factory.clients)-1

        #Once the client_id can be properly accessed, I want to store info as follows so that a connection can be paired with a user_id
        sql = "INSERT INTO user_db(user_id, user_name,cur_connect_idx) VALUES('%s','%s', '%d')" % (self.name, self.transport.getPeer().host,'',client_id)

    #Remaining code omitted for brevity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to put connection IDs into the database?

The database is where you keep *persistent* state.  Connections and connection IDs are transient state.

When you figure out which user a connection represents, put that information into a data structure on the factory (or some other long-lived object).

For example:

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    username = self._parseAndExtractUsername(data)
    if username is not None:
        self.factory.users[username] = self
```

Now you have a dictionary on the factory, shared between all of the protocol instances, which maps usernames to protocol instances.

Comment: I don't think I actually need connection IDs in the database, but it was the way I thought I could solve the problem of pairing the persistent database info with the transient user connection. I looked through some tutorials but never encountered anything that paired Twisted with persistent storage. How do you accomplish putting the user connection into "a data structure on the factory"?

Comment: Adding further that my current paradigm is to send a message to the server using the following structure: <user id, chat_text, recipient user id>. Once the message is received, the recipient user id should be used to map to its current server connection.

Comment: Hi!  I'm not going to write your program for you, sorry.  Is there something that's unclear about the answer I've given?  I think it contains all the pieces necessary to solve your problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for adding that code snippet to your response! Showing how the username can be used as a key makes everything clear. I would like to up-vote your response, but I don't have the 15 reputation needed to vote. I marked this as the answer accepted answer instead.